# How to insert same element on DIFFERENT positions of an array (in C)?

Tags: arrays, c

I need some assistance in C language.

Assuming I have an array of 10 elements:

```
int arr[10] = {1,2,999,4,5,999,7,999,9,10};
```

I want to add the number `1000` at every position where `999` is found without deleting it of course. Or in that case positions where 1000 has to be added: `arr[2]`, `arr[5]`, `arr[7]`

So my result buffer would be after compiling (of course increased by the amount of positions where 999 has been added):

```
temp[100] = {1,2,1000,999,4,5,1000,999,7,1000,999,9,10};
```

Can you help me with that?

Comment: If you need to insert a value into an array, you are probably using the wrong type of data structure for your needs.

Comment: You are not inserting anything: you are creating a new array. What did you try already?

Comment: It's not possible. The array `arr` can hold only 10 elements. You cannot add more. Therefore you have conflicting requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using conditionals like given below.

```
//I assume that the arrays are already declared
int i,j;
for(i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++ , j++){ //here n is the size of the array
    if(arr[j] == 999){
        temp[i] = 1000;
        i++; n++;
        temp[i] = 999;
    }
    else
        temp[i] = arr[j];
}
```

Try this out. This code snippet may not seem so standard but this gives you your desired output...

Comment: @Utkarsh Sahu : This works , my for-cycle was completely wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @VB - If this answers your question, clicking the accept check mark is a way to say _thanks_.

Comment: `//here n is the size of the array` might be better stated `//here n is the changing max index of temp array`.  (and `n` needs to be declared and initialized somewhere. eg `int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);`)

Comment: @ryyker yes you may say that.